# Dilation of an open subset of ${\bf R}^d$ is open?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In proving the dilation invariance of the Lebesgue measure on ${\bf R}^d$, I found that the following statement is crucial:

> The dilation $f(x)=\lambda x$ with $\lambda>0$ being a fixed number is an open map. In other word, if $E$ is an open subset of ${\bf R}^d$, then $f(E)$ is also open.

Working on the definition of "open" in a metric space, I can further reduce the problem to showing $f(B)$ is open for any open ball $B$. When the center of $B$ is the origin, there is no problem. How would one should the general case?

Comment: $f$ is a homeomorphism, hence is an open map.

Comment: The inverse $f^{-1}(x) = \lambda^{-1} x$ is continuous, which gives that $f(U)$ is open for any open $U$.

Comment: @carmichael561: How would you prove that $f$ is a homeomorphism in the first place?

Comment: @cderwin: This is very quick. I have asked a dumb question.

Comment: It's not hard to show that $f$ is bijective, and it's continuous because scalar multiplication is continuous in all topological vector spaces. Also, $f^{-1}(x) = \lambda^{-1}x$ is also continuous by the same reasoning. Thus, $f$ is a homeomorphism. This is a more general statement that can be extended to any TVS over an arbitrary field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general case is similar. If $B$ is an open ball of radius $r$ centered at $x_0$, then $f(B)$ is an open ball of radius $\lambda r$ centered at $\lambda x_0$.

Comment: I just didn't have any intuition that $f(B)$ is still a ball for any ball $B$. Really stupid.

Answer (score 1):

If $U$ is open and $\lambda >0$, fix some point $z \in \lambda U$.  Then $z = \lambda u$ for some $u \in U$.  Since $U$ is open, find $\epsilon > 0 $ so that $B_{\epsilon}(u) \subset U$.  Then I claim that $B_{\lambda\epsilon}(z) \subset \lambda U$:

given $y \in B_{\lambda \epsilon}(z)$, the point $\lambda^{-1}y$ satisfies

$|\lambda^{-1}y - u | = \lambda^{-1}|y - \lambda u| = \lambda^{-1} |y - z| < \lambda^{-1} \lambda \epsilon = \epsilon$

Hence $\lambda^{-1}y \in B_{\epsilon}(u) \subset U$.  So $\lambda (\lambda^{-1} y) \in \lambda U$ and the statement follows.